# Geotools NAVCONTransform constructor

Tags: java, navigation, transform, geotools

I'm having trouble getting NADCONTransform to work with GeoTools-9-SNAPSHOT.

My example looks like this:

```
String latGridFile = "C:/NADCON/Grids/conus.las"; <BR>
String longGridFile = "C:/NADCON/Grids/conus.los";

NADCONTransform transform = getNadconTransform(latGridFile, longGridFile);
```

etc...

My getNadconTransform method looks like this:

```
public NADCONTransform getNadconTransform(String latGridFile, String longGridFile) {<BR>
        File fLat = new File(latGridFile);<BR>
        File fLong = new File(longGridFile);

        if (!fLat.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(latGridFile +" does not exist");
        }
        if (!fLong.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(longGridFile+" does not exist");
        }

        URI uriLat = fLat.toURI();
        URI uriLong = fLong.toURI();



        NADCONTransform transform = new NADCONTransform(uriLat, uriLong);
                return transform;

    }
```

The conus las and los files exist, but when I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Could not locate grid file file:/C:/NADCON/Grids/conus.las
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.NADCONTransform.locateGrid(NADCONTransform.java:248)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.NADCONTransform.<init>(NADCONTransform.java:232)
```

I used to run this code just fine with GeoTools 2.6.4. In that version, the code worked directly with strings to the las and los files.  This new version works with URIs, and does not seem to work.

Any Ideas?